# Spring-JMS(Websphere MQ)

Tags: spring, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have the below configurations in Spring , it is working fine but performance is too low (it takes 1 min for 20 messages). Can you please suggest me changes to increase the performance.

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"> 
        <property name="transportType"><value>1</value></property> 
        <property name="queueManager"><value></value></property> 
        <property name="hostName"><value></value></property> 
        <property name="port"><value></value></property> 
        <property name="channel"><value></value></property> 
        <property name="clientId"><value></value></property>        
    </bean>
        <bean id="SenderJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"> 
        <property name="connectionFactory"><ref bean="jmsConnectionFactory" />  </property> 
        <property name="pubSubDomain"><value>false</value></property> 
        <property name="defaultDestination"><ref bean="senderQueue" /></property> 
    </bean>  
<bean id="senderQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"> 
        <constructor-arg value="TEST" /> 
        <property name="baseQueueManagerName"><value>tree.queue.manager</value></property> 
        <property name="baseQueueName"><value>ORANGE.QUEUE</value></property>  
    </bean> 
    <bean id="jmsSender" class="org.tree.jms.spring.JMSSender"> 
        <property name="jmsTemplate"><ref bean="SenderJMSTemplate"/></property>     
    </bean>
```

I am calling from spring as

```
JMSSender obj = (JMSSender) context.getBean("jmsSender");
```

And My Sender program is :

```
        @Cacheable("message")

     public void sendMesage() {

        jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
        public Message createMessage(Session session)throws JMSException {
        message = (Message) session.createTextMessage(stringBuffer.toString());
        return message;
        }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A common problem when using JMSTemplate to send messages out of JavaEE containers is the it's extremly slow since it acquires a new connection for each message (and then closes it). You would probably need a pooled/cached connection to gain speed here.

Read this article, it's written for ActiveMQ, but applies in a similar way to WebSphere MQ: http://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html

You can setup a cached connection factory in spring using something like this:

```
<bean id="cachedConnectionFactory"
class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="jmsConnectionFactory"
p:sessionCacheSize="10" />
```

Then use it instead of the original one for JMS connections.